# dynamic programming technique with inclusion-exclusion

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

There are N soldiers (numbered from 1 to N). Each soldier has some subset of skills out of M different skills (numbered from 1 to M). The skill-set of an army is the union of skill-sets of its constituent soldiers. How many different subsets of soldiers satisfy are there which have specific  skill-set requirement
[Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w16/challenges/vim-war)

According to the Explanation  problem reduces to finding the number of subsets of these numbers whose OR is exactly equal to the required value, say req
**Let f(i) be the number of numbers j such that j OR i = i.Then the answer is
 ∑i(−1)^popcount(i xor req)(2^f(i)−1) for all i such that i OR req is req**

How does this formula comes and how popcount describe that it added or subtracted.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: Without loss of generality, we can filter out the soldiers with at least one skill outside the required set.  Because the skills of a subset must be exactly the required set of skills, those soldiers will never be used.   Start by looking at the case M=2.

Comment: Also consider the special case where for each subset of req, there is exactly one soldier with this subset of skills.

Comment: would u explain in brief

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take at it.  The way to solve it: instead of reasoning on groups that **have** some set of skills,
let's reason on groups of soldiers that **do not have** some set of skills.
Because this second property propagates well from the group to all the members.

Before we start, a little simplification:

Without loss of generality, we can filter out the soldiers with at least one skill outside the required set. Because the skills of a subset must be exactly the required set of skills, those smart soldiers who know too much will never be needed.

From now on, we assume the required skill set is `{1, ... , R}` and that the skills of the soldiers are between `1` and `R`.

We are going to need this definition of `A_i` (where `i` belongs to `{1,..,R}`):

`A_i` : the set of groups of soldiers that have skill `i` **in their group skill set**.

In other words, a group in `A_i` (`inter` means the intersection) is a group where at least one soldier has skill number `i`.

Now if `i<j`,

`A_i inter A_j` = the groups of soldiers that have skills `i` and `j` **in their group skill set**.

In other words, a group in `A_i inter A_j` is a group with at least one of the properties

- one soldier with both skills number `i` and `j`.
- two soldiers, one with skill `i`, one with skill `j`.

And

```
A_1 inter A_2 ... inter A_R
```

is the set of groups of soldiers that do have skills `1,.., R` in their group skill set.

The question the problem is asking can be expressed with `A_i`:

What is the size of `A_1 inter A_2 ... inter A_R` ?

It is equal to

```
2^2^R - size( comp(A_1) union comp(A_2) ... union comp(A_R) )
```

where `comp(A)` is the complementary set.

Now, we can apply the inclusion-exclusion principle.

There is one more trick to make it computable:

If `I` is s subset of `{1,..,R}`, then the groups in

```
intersection(comp(A_j) for all j in I)
```

are the groups of soldiers with no skill (as a group) in `I`.
Note that a soldier in such a group is exactly a soldier who does not have any skill in `I`.
Let define `g(I)` as the number of soldier that do not have any skill in set `I`.  With that, we have

```
size( intersection(comp(A_j) for all j in I) ) = 2^g(I)
```

In the end, the result I have is:

```
2^2^R - sum( (-1)^(size(I)+1) * 2^g(I) , for each I subset of {1,..,R} and I non-empty)
```

I hope this helps.  Let me know if something is still unclear.